# Pushed with a non-Contributor account

Tags: git, gitlab

Hello I'm a bit new to git-hub so I don't get this:
I'm an owner of a repository, I tried making a new git-account then adjusted the global user and email in my machine (which has the account of the owner for the repository) and tried to push to the repository. It worked without adding the new account as a contributor and it didn't prompt me for username and password which was weird. The commit was with the name of a non-contributor account, according to my knowledge only contributors are allowed to make changes so I'm asking if there is something that I don't understand or should know about, since I might work on a shared pc and I wouldn't want to leave that kind of privilege on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate sets of identification here.  One of them is `user.name` and `user.email`, which are the personal name (not username) and email address that are stored in your commits as the author, committer, and tagger values.  These values show up when you do `git show` or `git log`.  The other is the credentials and username that are used to push to your hosting provider, such as GitHub or GitLab.  These two sets of identification are completely independent.

Most hosting providers allow you to push commits and tags that contain any author, committer, and tagger values.  This is because there are projects, such as Git itself, where the workflow happens on a mailing list, and consequently the author and committer are two different people, only the latter of which may have access to the repository in question.  It's also common for people to cherry-pick patches from other forks or even just submit work from other colleagues, in which case nobody listed on the commit may have access to the repository in question.

So in this case, what it sounds like is that your `user.name` and `user.email` values were set to the new account, but you were using your old credentials to push to the project.  If that's the case, and you want to use your new credentials, you should either create a new SSH key for the new account if you're using SSH or update the remote URL to include a username if you're using HTTPS, in which case Git will prompt you for the new password.

For HTTPS, if your remote were `https://github.com/git/git.git` and you wanted to change it to use account `bk2204`, you'd write this:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://bk2204@github.com/git/git.git
```

Comment: so from what i understood is that user.name and user.email are more of an identification to the computer not the mail necessarily the email that have access, im using http links so how should i update my credentials? and the no prompt password happens only on windows on Ubuntu i get prompted to type in my id/pass

Comment: Correct.  `user.name` and `user.email` are what show up as Author and Committer fields in `git show` and `git log`; they have nothing to do with authentication at all.  I've updated the body of the text with an example to show you how to configure your remote.